# Send signal to Alfresco server

Tags: java, web-services, triggers, signals, alfresco

I'm interested in sending a signal to Alfresco server in order for it to read a file from a local disk. Can this be done using web services from an external source (cURL, Java Project, something similar)? For example a ping to the server in order trigger a chain of events. Any suggestion is useful. Thank you!

Comment: Loads of ways! All of which require a little bit of coding though (mostly to implement your logic).

Answer (score 0):

The Alfresco bulkimport tool (yourHost:port/alfresco/alfresco/service/bulkfsimport) provides that piece of functionality.
It's backed by a webscript and can be called using cUrl or any other http client api.

If you prefer a custom implementation I would go for a java backed Alfresco webscript as well.
A Web Script is simply a service bound to a URI which responds to HTTP methods such as GET, POST, PUT and DELETE.

See the webscript documentation for details:
http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/ws-and-Java.html

Answer (score 0):

To trigger an action on the server side you can create a [Custom Action](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Custom_Actions). Normally a custom action can be configured to be accessible from Alfresco Web Client or Alfresco Share. In your case you can invoke the action by calling it from a custom [Webscript](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts) and using the [Actions API](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_API#Actions_API) to invoke your custom action. The Webscript itself can then be invoked by a simple REST based call using curl, Java or any other method.